# Powershell Custom Object property order issue

Tags: powershell, object

When creating a custom object in powershell my properties are not ordering in the same precedence I type them in (top to bottom -> left to right).

I was told to use [ordered] on my table declaration as done below;

```
$AllMailData += New-Object PSObject -Property [ordered]@{
            'Unique ID' = $sharedmail.PrimarySmtpAddress
            'Display Name' = $sharedmail.DisplayName
        }
```

However this gives me a syntax error. Can anyone suggest where I have gone wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't rely on property order, but rather on their names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get rid of the error when you enclose everything you're passing to `-Property` in parenthesis `()`.

Also shorter way of writing this would be:

```
$AllMailData += [PSCustomObject]@{
            'Unique ID' = $sharedmail.PrimarySmtpAddress
            'Display Name' = $sharedmail.DisplayName
        }
```

`[PSCustomObject]` guarantees preservation of property order, where `[PSObject]` does not. But it seems that using ordered hashtable in your example accomplishes that, too.